# How to split String into two parts?

Tags: java, string, split

I have the following String,

```
String Place =  "3030XR Amsterdam";
```

I want to get it like

```
String postcode = "3030XR";
String City = "Amsterdam";
```

Can somebody help me.

Comment: Everyone can help you if you show some efforts!!!

Comment: Use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and be happy.

Comment: that's not called `trim`. That's called `split`.

Comment: After you've happily split your String, follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) please.

Answer (score 9):

Try `Place.split(" ");`  split the string.It will retrun String array

```
String splitted[]=Place.split(" ");
System.out.println(splitted[0]);
System.out.println(splitted[1]);
```

As @ᴍarounᴍaroun has suggested you can also use regex this way

```
 Place.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: `\\s+` might be better as it's more general, e.g. `"3030XR______Amsterdam"` (Where `_` is a space).

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun Thanks for your suggesstion.I will modify it

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun modified the answer.Please have a look

Comment: Also change the var name 'Place' to lower case.

Comment: @thiago.lenz OP's String is `Place`

Comment: @rocking String place, not String Place. Java conventions.

Comment: @thiago.lenz Yes true but OP is using String Place.So I just said Place.split().I was referring to OP String Name

Comment: @Muratcan Accepting answer is the stackoverflow of way of saying thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
Place.split("\\s+");
```

to split at empty spaces